# Add class Ruby on rails select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to add `myClass`. Help please

```
<%= select_hour(@work_hour, 
field_name: 'hour',  
start_hour: @start, 
end_hour:@end  )  %>
```

```
<%= select_hour(@work_hour, 
field_name: 'hour',  
start_hour: @start,
end_hour:@end,  
:class => 'form-control'  )  %>
```

Comment: select_hour(@work_hour, 
field_name: 'hour',  
start_hour: @start,
end_hour:@end, html_options: {class: 'myClass'})

Comment: What is `myClass` (a string a Ruby class)? Where do you want to add it to (as a CSS class or to grab data from for the form)?

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_hour) say, you can pass `html_options` hash as the third argument in this method:

```
<%= select_hour(@work_hour, { field_name: 'hour', start_hour: @start, end_hour: @end }, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Notice explicit `{}` used to separate second argument (hash delimited with `{}` from third argument (hash with no explicit `{}` delimitation, since you can do it with the hash being last argument passed to a method).